# ESRI ArcObjects and Unit Testing the Geoprocessor dll

Tags: arcobjects, c#, .net, unit-testing

I have an issue with using ArcObjects and the Geoprocessor .dll library in a UnitTest environment (MSTest) in Visual Studio. When I test a program that creates an ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessor object and I try to use it I get an error thrown:

*System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
                Debug Trace:
Could not load file or assembly 'GpMetadataFunctions, Version=10.2.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=8fc3cc631e44ad86' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.*

This always occurs when I Debug and step through the Unit test. Running the Unit Test (no step through in the debugger) will cause the test to stay pending indefinitely.

**Details:**

Everything works fine when run in the program itself or call the program from a separate VS project. This issue only occurs when I attempt to call the method from a Unit test style project.

I'm new to Unit Testing with .NET so there could be something inherent to the way it works that I am not understanding.

**Tried:**

- seem able to test other ArcGIS COM and other 3rd party libraries/dlls so am assuming something particular to the way the Geoprocessor class/library/dll is invoked is issue (hence post on gis stack exchange).
- Tried on other machines with same behavior.
- tried on VS 2010 with same behaviour (I'm running VS2015)
- tried with Admin rights for Visual Studio

I have found posts of users running unit tests on ArcObjects including from ESRI so I know that it is being done but code examples are scarce. Any thoughts or advice is welcome.

Update/Correction:
If I load GPMetadataFunctions.dll from the ArcGIS installation folder into the project or the GAC of the targeted .NET framework the test *will run* but it will still fail when stepping through in the debugger. When it fails I get the same message as above without debug trace.

**Example:**
***Project.cs***

```
using ESRI.ArcGIS.ConversionTools;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.esriSystem;
using ESRI.ArcGIS.Geoprocessor;
using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices; //added to allow testing of private methods

[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("ArcObjectsSampleTests")]
namespace ArcObjectsSample
{
class Program
{
    [STAThread()]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        ProcessStuff myProcessStuff = new ProcessStuff();
        myProcessStuff.OpenFolder();
        myProcessStuff.Run(
            @"C:\temp\test\foo.shp",
            @"C:\temp\test\",
            "fooCopy.shp"
            );
    }
}


internal class ProcessStuff
{
    internal ProcessStuff()
    {
        //Get a license checked out:
        ESRI.ArcGIS.RuntimeManager.Bind(ESRI.ArcGIS.ProductCode.Desktop);
        IAoInitialize aoInitialize = new AoInitializeClass();
        esriLicenseStatus stat;
        stat = aoInitialize.Initialize(esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeBasic);
        // if not licensed - initialize license
        if (stat == esriLicenseStatus.esriLicenseNotLicensed) stat = aoInitialize.Initialize(esriLicenseProductCode.esriLicenseProductCodeAdvanced);
    }

    internal void Run(string inputFC, string outputPath, string outputFCName)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Starting");
        Geoprocessor gp = new Geoprocessor();
        gp.OverwriteOutput = true;

       //Testing fails on the following line below (does not matter what is set as workspace)
        gp.SetEnvironmentValue("workspace", "c:/temp");
        FeatureClassToFeatureClass featureClassTool = new FeatureClassToFeatureClass();
        featureClassTool.in_features = inputFC; 
        featureClassTool.out_path = outputPath; 
        featureClassTool.out_name = outputFCName;

        gp.Execute(featureClassTool, null);


        Console.WriteLine("Done");
        Console.WriteLine("Press any key to close...");
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

}
}
```

***UnitTest Project.cs***

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;
using ArcObjectsSample;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ArcObjectsSample.Tests
{
[TestClass()]
public class ProcessStuffTests
{
    [TestMethod()]
    [STAThread]
    public void RunTest()
    {


       ProcessStuff myProcessStuff = new ProcessStuff();

        myProcessStuff.Run(
            @"C:\temp\test\foo.shp",
            @"C:\temp\test\",
            "fooCopy.shp"
            );


        //myProcessStuff.OpenFolder();
        //do some test of the results here
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Wild guess: verify both projects target the same platform (x86, x64) and not Any CPU.

Comment: Good point. I should have mentioned that I do have both projects targeting x86 with this behaviour. That was ESRI Canada's only advice also.

Comment: 2nd wild guess: is GPMetadataFunctions in the GAC?  See this thread: https://community.esri.com/thread/14848 even though the issue is with Python.

Comment: Gave that a try. When it is loaded I no longer get the Debug Trace portion of the above error but I still get the same _System.AccessViolationException_ message. Same behaviour as if I loaded the dll as a project reference.

Comment: Correction/Update: The test works with GPMetadataFunctions added as a reference if I run it. It only fails if I step through in the debugger. I'm going to update my question accordingly. @RichardMorgan +1